# Origin of exception message in datetime module. ValueError: year 10000 is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, cpython

Using Python 3.8:

```py
In [12]: datetime(10000, month=2, day=1)       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-f4737756e718> in <module>
----> 1 datetime(10000, month=2, day=1)

ValueError: year 10000 is out of range
```

Note that I'm aware that datetime.datetime doesn't support years with five digits, so I'm not asking why 10000 doesn't work.

I was wondering where the message of the ValueError exception comes from as I don't see anything like `year {year} is out of range` in the [lib/datetime.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py) code.

The only similarity is in the [line 894](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L894) but is not the same message.

Comment: maybe due to the different version of the library

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

datetime.MAXYEAR

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8 and checking the library against the branch 3.8 in the cpython repository

Comment: Search for `MAXYEAR` in the code. I think I found that message at [Modules/_datetimemodule.c line 420](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L420) but I'm not sure what that file is for

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks, seems likely to be the origin of the message. Although I don't understand how does it reach that point coming from the datetime.py

Comment: @Jon [`_datetime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6371) is the Fast implementation of the datetime type written in `C`. This fast implementation will be used if it is available on your system otherwise the [pure python implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L1558) will be used. This is done by the  import at the bottom of  [`datetime.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L2500)

Comment: The cextension-module is called `_datetime` and gets imported here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96b1c59c71534db3f0f3799cd84e2006923a5098/Lib/datetime.py#L2504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual implementation of `datetime.datetime` is in [`_datetimemodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c) and not in [`datetime.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py).

In the C implementation, you can see, as @wjandrea mentioned `PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "year %i is out of range", year);` in function `check_date_args` in [line 420](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L420).
That one ends up being called from `datetime_new`, which is used to construct `datetime.datetime`, see [line 6334](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6334).

And about the question how it goes from `datetime.py` to the c implementation, there is [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L2500):

```
from _datetime import *
```

Comment: Nice answer. One quick suggestion,IMHO "The actual implementation of `datetime.datetime` is in `_datetimemodule.c` and **not in `datetime.py`**", This statement is bit misleading. The implementation is available in both [python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/datetime.py#L1558) level and [C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6298) level.